# How to delete all <li> with innerHTML = = "";

Tags: javascript

My html code

```
<ul id = "1">
<li>elti</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

to delete the empty li I'm using the below javascript code:

```
var y = document.getElementById("1");
x = y.getElementsByTagName("li");


for( i = 0; i < x.length ; i++) {
    if (x[i].innerHTML === "" ){
        y.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
}
```

but the  output is this:

```
<li>elti</li>
<li></li>
```

as you can see it doesn't delete a li tag. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `x` is going to keep changing as you remove elements from it.  After a few iterations, `x[i]` is no longer going to be what you think it is.

Comment: ID attributes must start with a letter (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: @jeff Numeric IDs are valid in HTML 5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work in reverse; else when you delete an item, you skip the check of the next item in the list:

```
for( i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (x[i].innerHTML === "" ){
    y.removeChild(x[i]);
  }
}
```

```js
var y = document.getElementById("1");
x = y.getElementsByTagName("li");


for( i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (x[i].innerHTML === "" ){
    y.removeChild(x[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id = "1">
  <li>elti</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 This is because when you delete an element, all indexes move 1 to the left, but your `i` iteration variable doesn't account for it

Comment: This is correct. He could also just decrement his index when he removes an element `y.removeChild(x[i--]);`